# Is there a way to force reading encoding on XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding

Here's my problem. I need to pass an XML file through an XSLT but the first line states that the file is utf-8 encoded, but it is windows-1251 in reality. Except for that, everything is fine.

Is it possible to force the readings to ignore this statement and use the correct encoding?

Sample entry (I changed the encoding manually and it worked):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" standalone="yes"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <nome><![CDATA[Unicode character here: é]]></nome>
  </item>
</products>
```

Comment: How are you calling the XSLT?  The answer will be language/processor specific, e.g. in Java (`javax.xml.transform`) you could use a `StreamSource` created from a `Reader` to force a particular encoding.

Comment: A one-line `sed` script to change the encoding attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> in Java (javax.xml.transform) you could use a StreamSource created from a Reader to force a particular encoding.
>
> A one-line sed script to change the encoding attribute